# VBox in HBox via controller

Tags: javascript, sapui5

With this code i want to create 4 VBoxes in one HBox

```
        var count= 4;

        var hbox = new sap.m.HBox("HBox", {
            width: "100%"
        });

        for(var i = 0; i <= count; i++){
            new sap.m.VBox("V_" + i, {
                width: "100px",
                height: "200px",
            }).placeAt(hbox);
        };
        this.getView().byId("myContainer").addContent(hbox);
```

But there is only the HBox without Vboxes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look in the jsbin [example](http://jsbin.com/mibaguluku/1/edit?html,js,output), is it layout what you are looking for?

```
var oLabelA = new sap.m.Label({text:"A"});
var oLabelB = new sap.m.Label({text:"B"});
var oLabelC = new sap.m.Label({text:"C"});
var oLabelD = new sap.m.Label({text:"D"});

var oVbox1 = new sap.m.VBox({width: "100%"}); 
var oVbox2 = new sap.m.VBox({width: "100%"}); 
var oVbox3 = new sap.m.VBox({width: "100%"}); 
var oVbox4 = new sap.m.VBox({width: "100%"}); 

oVbox1.addItem(oLabelA);
oVbox2.addItem(oLabelB);
oVbox3.addItem(oLabelC);
oVbox4.addItem(oLabelD);

var hbox = new sap.m.HBox({ width: "100%"}); 

hbox.addItem(oVbox1);
hbox.addItem(oVbox2);
hbox.addItem(oVbox3);
hbox.addItem(oVbox4);
```

Comment: Hey @Jaro , How can we delete the addedItems (not destroying whole VBox) but just items here ?

Comment: Hi,e.g. like this: oVbox4.removeItem(oLabelD); or hbox.removeItem(oVbox4);

Comment: thanks @Jaro , i got this :) .... also searched docs and came to know how to remove all items  .... hbox.removeAllItems();

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you used a **placeAt** function to place the control. The [placeAt](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html#placeAt) function is used to place a SAPUI5 control in a HTML DOM Element or within a control if it has an aggregation called **content**, however to place it within other aggregations you will have use it's specific setter/getter & add/remove functions.

The HBox in this case, extends the FlexBox control which has an **items** aggregation. So it will have the [addItem](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.FlexBox.html#addItem) method to add a control.

```
var count = 4;

        var hbox = new sap.m.HBox("HBox", {
            width: "100%"
        });

        for (var i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
            hbox.addItem(new sap.m.VBox("V_" + i, {
                width: "100px",
                height: "200px",
            }));
        };
        this.getView().byId("myContainer").addContent(hbox);
```

Comment: Hey @Stephen S , May i know how could we delete the added Items (`Vbox` es) not destroying whole `Hbox` ....for eg: if `myContainer` already have a `Hbox` and this `Hbox` have items how could we remove that ?

Comment: I'm sorry I cant help much....haven't seen any UI5 for some years now. I think you should create a new question for this.